# How to zoom in and zoom out on custom zoom button in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, zooming

I am new to iphone, I am using overlay view to create *zoom in* and *zoom out* buttons, 
now, i want to zoom in and out on clicking buttons placed for zoom in and zoom out.
how to do it? Is there any option? if anyone knows please help me.

```
imgpicker.cameraViewTransform=CGAffineTransformScale(imgpicker.cameraViewTransform,CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X+50, CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y+50);
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use a UIScrollView and add those actions:

```
-(IBAction)zoom_p:(id)sender
{
    zoom += 0.2f;
    [scrollView setZoomScale:zoom];
}

-(IBAction)zoom_m:(id)sender
{
    if (zoom > 0.5f) {
        zoom -= 0.2f;
        [scrollView setZoomScale:zoom];
    }
}
```